# ASP.net MVC 5 calling partial view thats in layout from Home controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

Hey all I am trying to find a way (or if its possible) to call this code:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @if (Session["chosenAMT"] is bool == true)
        {
           @Html.Partial("_Menu")
        }
    </ul>
</nav>
```

When it starts the page the value for **chosenAMT** is **false** so the navigation does not load up on the **_Layout.cshtml** page.

However, once the user selects a value from the dropdown I need to **enable** that partial view to be called so that it can show to the user the navigation now.

When the user selects a value from the dropdown list I call a **POST** to the **HomeController.cs**:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'Home/showNav',
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {},
  success: function (response) {
     console.log('worked');
  },
  error: function (response) {
     console.log(response);
  }
});
```

And this is the **showNav** code in the **HomeController.cs**:

```
[HttpPost]
public string showNav()
{
   Dictionary<string, string> resultsBack = new Dictionary<string, string>();

   Session["chosenAMT"] = true;

   resultsBack.Add("dback", "GOOD");
   resultsBack.Add("dhead", "worked");
   resultsBack.Add("dinfo", "called nav");

   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allData, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

*I'm pretty much stuck there* as to how to go about making the call back to the **_Layout.cshtml** page in order to show the navigation now...

Any help would be great! Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Got it!

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
 <nav id="menuContainer" data-url="@Url.Action("Menu","Home")">                    
    @Html.Action("Menu")
 </nav>
```

**_Menu.cshtml:**

```
 @if (Session["chosenAMT"].ToString() == "True")
 {
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    etc...etc....
    </ul>
 }
```

**index.js:**

```
 success: function (response) {
    var url = $("#menuContainer").data("url");

    $("#menuContainer").load(url);
 },
```

**HomeController:**

```
 public ActionResult Menu()
 {
    return PartialView("_Menu");
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to dynamically reload that part of the menu. To start, create an action method which returns the markup for the menu.

```
public ActionResult Menu()
{
   return PartialView("Menu");
}
```

You may also move your `if` condition statement inside the partial view to conditionally render some markup. So your `Menu.cshtml` will be like

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @if (Session["chosenAMT"] is bool == true)
        {
           @Html.Partial("_Menu")
        }
    </ul>
```

Now call this action method inside the outer container element.

```
<nav id="menuContainer" data-url="@Url.Action("Menu","YourControllerName")">
   @Html.Action("Menu")
</nav>
```

Now all you have to do is, reloading the content of this menu container div on the success event of your ajax call. You can use the jQuery `load` method

```
success: function (response) {
     var url = $("#menuContainer").data("url");
     $("#menuContainer").load(url);
},
```

Comment: Hum.. thanks Shyju but im a little confused as the the **Menu.cshtml**? I have a **_Menu.cshtml** file that houses the **navigation links**. The **_Layout.cshtml** is where the **<Nav >** part is that I currently have the **IF** code.

Comment: You need to move that if condition to some place where it gets executed when you reload it. So the new partial view would the best place for that. this view code will be executed when you invoke the `Menu` action method.

Comment: So the **<nav id="menuContainer"** needs to be in the **_Layout.cshtml** page? And the **IF** condiction needs to be in my **_Menu.cshtml** page?

Comment: Yes. You can put the `if` condition inside the `_Menu` or `Menu` Or even you can merge the two partial views to one. All you need is an action method which renders the menu markup (the view involved with this action method should have the if condition). When your ajax call success event happens, you reload the container div by calling this action method again

Comment: Check out my OP for an update, Shyju... Still not understanding.

Comment: You should include the menu in the layout page via an action method as i explained in the answer.

Comment: Please label your code by which controller/view it should be inserted into.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148443/discussion-between-shyju-and-stealthrt).

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, Shyju! :o)